# Error when installing XLConnect in RStudio

Tags: windows-7, rstudio, xlconnect

Thanks in advance.
I am trying to install XLConnect package. I am using RStudio. For your information rJava is installed.

Here is my command in R and the error message:

> install.packages("XLConnect")

trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.1/XLConnect_0.2-7.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 17997942 bytes (17.2 Mb)
opened URL
downloaded 16.7 Mb

Warning in install.packages : downloaded length 17473536 != reported length 17997942

Warning in install.packages : error 1 in extracting from zip file

Warning in install.packages : cannot open compressed file 'XLConnect/DESCRIPTION', probable reason 'No such file or directory'

Error in install.packages : cannot open the connection

Answer (score 0):

The warnings indicate that something is corrupting the package download. Quite often the reason is a corporate firewall. You might want to check with your IT whether this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing using standard R and the standard R will tell you where is package zip file is saved. Then you can install using RStudio by installing package from local zip file.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue while downloading some package. Try re-installing the package cran using

`install.packages("CRAN")`

See if it works, if the issue of unmatched length persists uninstall RStudio and install it again.

That seemed to have worked for me.