# How to install 'XLConnect'-package in R correctly

Tags: r, xlconnect

I am very new to this community.
My aim is to use R for statistical analysis but some errors occurred.

In the first step, I want to load the "XLConnect"-package, in order to open an xlsx-data file, with this code:

`install.packages('XLConnect')
library(XLConnect)`

Answer was "package ‘XLConnect’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked", after which the following error was given:

> Error in library(XLConnect) : the package ‘XLConnect’ doesn't exist.

I also tried the xlsx package, but in this case always got:

> Error in -library('openxlsx') : invalid argument to unary operator

or, that the package openxlsx, doesn't exist but some line before it told me the download, installation and check sums were correct!

Additionally, when I try to change the directory in a script, using
`getwd()`, the following error occurs:

> Error in -getwd() : invalid argument to unary operator

When I type it in the console it works.

I downloaded R here: https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base,  installed R version 3.4.3 as well as R Studio.
I already looked in the community for some hints but neither could solve my problem:

- [XLConnect function is not passing argument to system.file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36192312/xlconnect-function-is-not-passing-argument-to-system-file)
- [Error when installing XLConnect in RStudio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24576507/error-when-installing-xlconnect-in-rstudio)

MY OS is Windows 10, I tried the 32-bit as well as the 64-bit version of R and installed fitting Java-Versions for both verisons( that was the first error that occured but now isn't there anymore).

I tried to load the packages from several CRAN-Mirrors but always the same error occurs (e.g. Germany(Göttingen),Germany(Münster), Belgium(Ghent) or Switzerland ).
Maybe I missed some very basic setting. Is the information I provided enough or do you need more?

Thanks a lot in advance for your support!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a lot! I installed java 32-bit and 64-bit versions the way it is recommended here: https://www.r-statistics.com/2012/08/how-to-load-the-rjava-package-after-the-error-java_home-cannot-be-determined-from-the-registry/ and I installed the rJava package like this: install.packages("rJava")
library(rJava)    and here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/176115/what-is-the-best-way-of-installing-the-r-package-xlconnect I found that this here should work to register R correctly: sudo R CMD javareconf but then I get the error that the console got an unexpected symbol.     Or Do you know how to register Java Development Kit  in R correctly. I installed jdk-8u161-windows-x64.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have Java Development Kit installed and correctly registered in R.

Comment: I installed java 32-bit and 64-bit versions the way it is recommended here: https://www.r-statistics.com/2012/08/how-to-load-the-rjava-package-after-the-error-java_home-cannot-be-determined-from-the-registry/